# Как поменять автора коммитов в bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

Создал новый аккаунт на bitbucket и на нем новый репозиторий и сделал первый коммит. Но автором коммита оказался мой старый аккаунт на bitbucket.
Видимо, где-то на компе нужно поменять конфиги бакета. Вопрос: где?
Или как сменить автора коммитов?

Comment: может в гит консоль https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git

Comment: git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com - если вы об этом, то это исключительно для гита.

Comment: угу, почитай, может еще что-то изменить захочешь.

Comment: А разве битбакет не хранилище для гита? Только изменение конфига поможет только новым коммитам.

Answer (score 3):

Git обозначает авторство парой *«имя — e-mail»*. Bitbucket же отображает эту пару на учётную запись того или иного пользователя, основываясь на содержимом раздела *«Bitbucket settings → GENERAL → Email addresses»*.

Соответственно, авторство можно переназначить **прямо на сайте, без перезаписи репозитория**. Для этого необходимо перенести e-mail адреса из вышеуказанного раздела из старой учётной записи в новую.

После этой манипуляции все коммиты на Bitbucket, когда-либо выполненные от имени старой учётной записи, тут же будут переназначены новой учётной записи.